# FileUpload is not making the upload of all files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

everyone! I already have been searching on this issue, but couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

There are some pages on our website where the users make multiple uploads of files. Today, we found out that some images are not being uploaded. I started debugging the code and was able to realise that is something related to thread. It seems that the code is running so fast that, before it was able to upload one file, another one is already being processed.

We don't get any error message, only that the upload is not working correctly.

In aspx:

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="True"/>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Label ID="lbSuccess" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False" 
    CssClass="sucesso_bold">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lbError" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False" 
    CssClass="erro_bold" ></asp:Label>
```

In the CodeBehind:

```
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                int arquivos = FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count();
                int count = FileUpload1.PostedFiles.SelectMany(file => 
   dtRetorno.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(linha => file.ContentType == 
   linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString())).Count();

                if (count != arquivos)
                    Util.Msg("Existe algum arquivo com o formato não aceito para o tipo de documento selecionado!", Page);

                //Verifica se pasta existe
                if (!Directory.Exists(caminho + associado))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho + associado);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Util.Msg("Caminho do GED especificado em local sem permissão ou inválido!", Page);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                #region upload

                foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
                {
                    Boolean erroCorrente = false;
                    foreach (DataRow linha in dtRetorno.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(linha => file.ContentType == linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString()))
                    {
                        mime = linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString();

                        nomeArquivo = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") + linha["GAA_TX_SUFIXO"];
                        var caminhoArquivo = Util.TratarCaminho(caminho + associado) + nomeArquivo;

                        Size? dimensaoImagem = null;
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoDocumento.SelectedValue) == ParametrosGeraisNegocios.ObterIdGTDLogoCarne() && (linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/jpeg" || linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/png"))
                        {
                            dimensaoImagem = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(linha["GDI_NR_Largura_PX"]), Convert.ToInt32(linha["GDI_NR_ALTURA_PX"]));
                        }

                        var tamanho = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(file.ContentLength);
                        var max = Convert.ToDouble(linha["GAT_NR_TAMANHO_MAXIMO_MB"]);
                        if (tamanho > max)
                        {
                            var comprimido = false;

                            #region Comprimir Imagem

                            if (linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/jpeg" ||
                                linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/png" ||
                                linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/bmp")
                            {
                                file.SaveAs(caminhoArquivo);
                                var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(caminhoArquivo);

                                var caminhoArquivoMod = caminhoArquivo + ".mod" + linha["GAA_TX_SUFIXO"];
                                try
                                {
                                    if (dimensaoImagem.HasValue)
                                    {
                                        var imagemRedimensionada = ImagemUtil.Resize(img, dimensaoImagem.Value);
                                        img.Dispose();
                                        img = imagemRedimensionada;
                                    }
                                    ComprimirImagem(img, 40L, caminhoArquivoMod);
                                    if (ConvertBytesToMegabytes(new FileInfo(caminhoArquivoMod).Length) <= max)
                                    {
                                        comprimido = true;
                                        img.Dispose();
                                        if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivo)) File.Delete(caminhoArquivo);
                                        if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivoMod))
                                            File.Move(caminhoArquivoMod, caminhoArquivo);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        img.Dispose();
                                        if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivo)) File.Delete(caminhoArquivo);
                                        if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivoMod)) File.Delete(caminhoArquivoMod);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    img.Dispose();
                                    if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivo)) File.Delete(caminhoArquivo);
                                    if (File.Exists(caminhoArquivoMod)) File.Delete(caminhoArquivoMod);
                                }

                            }

                            #endregion

                            if (!comprimido)
                            {
                                lbError.Text = lbError.Text + @"O arquivo " + file.FileName + @" excedeu o limite de " + max + @"MB!<br>";
                                lbError.Visible = true;
                                erroCorrente = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            file.SaveAs(caminhoArquivo);

                            #region Comprimir Imagem
                            if (linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/jpeg" ||
                                linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/png" ||
                                linha["GAA_TX_MIME_TYPE"].ToString() == "image/bmp")
                            {
                                var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(caminhoArquivo);
                                if (dimensaoImagem.HasValue)
                                {
                                    var imagemRedimensionada = ImagemUtil.Resize(img, dimensaoImagem.Value);
                                    img.Dispose();
                                    img = imagemRedimensionada;
                                }
                                var caminhoArquivoMod = caminhoArquivo + ".mod" + linha["GAA_TX_SUFIXO"];
                                ComprimirImagem(img, 40L, caminhoArquivoMod);
                                img.Dispose();
                                File.Delete(caminhoArquivo);
                                File.Move(caminhoArquivoMod, caminhoArquivo);
                            }

                            #endregion


                        if (erroCorrente) continue;

                        if (txtObservacoes.Text.Length > 550)
                            txtObservacoes.Text = txtObservacoes.Text.Substring(0, 550);

                        var objGEDdocumento = new GEDdocumentoObjetos
                        {
                            GDO_BL_REMOVIDO = false,
                            GDO_DT_ARMAZENAMENTO = DateTime.Now,
                            GDO_TX_ARQUIVO = nomeArquivo,
                            GTD_ID_GED_TIPO_DOCUMENTO = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoDocumento.SelectedValue),
                            USU_TX_ARMAZENOU = usuMatricula,
                            USU_ID_USUARIO = usuId,
                            GDO_TX_MIME_TYPE = mime
                        };
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtObservacoes.Text))
                            objGEDdocumento.GDO_TX_OBSERVACAO = txtObservacoes.Text;

                        gedNegocios.InserirDocumento(objGEDdocumento);

                        lbSuccess.Visible = true;
                        lbSuccess.Text = lbSuccess.Text + @"O arquivo " + file.FileName + @" foi enviado com sucesso!<br>";
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                Util.Msg("Nenhum arquivo encontrado. Favor selecionar os aquivos que deseja enviar!", Page);
                return;
            }
```

I put a thread.sleep(1000) after saving the image, and it worked, but i think the solution is not clean and can cause future problems.

Comment: where in the code exactly did you add the thread.sleep to make it temporary work?

Comment: also I can see many move and delete calls, are you sure the file is not getting deleted or moved after upload?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy i removed from the code to post here. but i put it after this line gedNegocios.InserirDocumento(objGEDdocumento);, that is the method that upload the file into the database.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy yes, because when i put the thread.sleep(), all the files are uploaded successfully, whislt when i remove the line, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I tried and traced the code as much as I could , but couldn't find a good reason for what you are getting, you will need to give it another try and debug more